# nginx wont restart after adding www subdomain

Tags: nginx

I followed tutorial http://wpmu.org/wordpress-multisite-wordpress-nginx and try to add the www subdomain to route to the same location as the domain in my config file.

Only problem, after editing, nginx wont restart...if i delete www.example.com it works perfectly.

Some help would be appreciated!

My config file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
root /var/www/wordpress;
access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log;
include conf.d/restrictions.conf;
include /var/www/wordpress/nginx.conf;
include conf.d/wordpress.conf;
}
```

Comment: What errors does nginx report? Try `sudo nginx -t` to test your config.

Comment: There should not be any problem with that configuration. The only idea that occurs to me is that you may have www.example.com declared somewhere else and nginx may be complaining about it.

Comment: The error returned was:

nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32

I edited the nginx.conf and it works but what did I do exactly? :)

And also the www.example.com seems te redirect to example.com, any way to leave that www.example.com? Or are those DNS settings?